# How to make my own evil(?) mode? view mode while debugging?

Tags: evil, read-only-mode

I'd like to switch between two modes

- source editing mode
- debug mode (where source is read-only, and you can use all other regular emacs commands + some debug related hot keys (such as `n` for next)

The workflow I'm looking for is this

- open a file
- start debugging
- open a debug control pannel (which key window)

  - while this pannel is open, I'm on debug mode (similar to view-mode)
- toggle the control pannel with a key to enter into a source editing mode (regular emacs mode)

I was thinking to turn on `view-mode` but I have to manage every single buffer I open with `view-mode`

`evil` does something similar but I would need to change so many key bindings.
I tried spacemacs's hybrid state. but now sure how much I have to change the key binding..

Answer (score 0):

I almost got it working

using spacemacs's hybrid

- emacs mode for source editing
- motion mode for debugging